# Angular2 - Testing call with a debounceTime

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular, typescript

I'm using a form control that detects changes using `valueChanges` and `debounceTime`. I'm writing a test that spies on `itemService` to check if the `update` method is being called. If I remove the `debounceTime` from the form control the test works fine.

Here's the form control in the component.

```
this.itemControl.valueChanges.debounceTime(300).subscribe(response => {
   this.itemService.update(response);
});
```

Here's the test

```
it('should do stuff',
    inject([ItemService], (itemService) => {
      return new Promise((res, rej) =>{
        spyOn(itemService, 'update');
        let item = {
            test: 'test'
        };
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
          let itemControl = new FormControl('test');
          fixture.componentInstance.itemControl = itemControl;
          fixture.autoDetectChanges();

          fixture.componentInstance.saveItem(item);
          expect(itemService.update).toHaveBeenCalled();

})}));
```

Here's the component's saveItem function

```
saveItem(item): void {
    this.itemControl.setValue(item);
}
```

Like I said, if I remove `debounceTime` from the form control the test executes fine, but I can't do that. I've tried adding a `tick()` call before the `expect` call but I just get this error

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: The code should be running in the fakeAsync zone to call this function ; Zone: ProxyZone ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: The code should be running in the fakeAsync zone to call this function Error: The code should be running in the fakeAsync zone to call this function
```

Comment: I think you need to wrap the test in `async` to use `tick`. One option with denouncing is to inject the debounce time, so you can set it to small number to keep your tests fast.

Comment: doesn't matter how long the debounce time is, could be 0 or 1. The test fails with `Expected spy update to have been called.`

Answer (score 48):

You should use **fakeAsync()** and **tick()**. Check out the **code below** (the .spec.ts file) that ran successfully on my end based on your test code in question.

**Explanation of code below:**
`fakeAsync()` and `tick()` should always be used together. You can use `async()/fixtureInstance.whenStable()` together, but it is less "predictable" from a programmer's perspective. I would recommend you to use `fakeAsync()/tick()` whenever you can. You should [only](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#fake-async) use `async()/fixtureInstance.whenStable()` when your test code makes an XHR call (aka testing Http request).

It's best to use `fakeAsync()/tick()` when you can because you have manual control over how async code operate in your test code.

As you can see in the code below (.spec.ts file). It is very important for you to call the tick method with the method parameter `300`, `tick(300)`, because the debounce value you set was `300`. If you hypothetically set your debounce value to `500`, then your tick value should be `500` in your testing code, if you want it to pass in this situation.

You will notice that if you set `tick(299)` your test will fail, but that is correct because you set your debounce value to `300`. This shows you the power of using `fakeAsync()/tick()`, you control your code timing (you are MASTER OF TIME, when you use `fakeAsync()/tick()`).

---

```
// component.sandbox.spec.ts
import { async, TestBed, fakeAsync, tick, inject } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { SandboxComponent } from "./component.sandbox";
import { ItemService } from "../../Providers";
import "rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime";

describe("testFormControl", () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
      declarations: [SandboxComponent],
      providers: [ItemService],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  // The test you had questions about :)
  it("(fakeAsync usage) Should hit the ItemService instance's 'update' method once", fakeAsync(inject([ItemService], (itemService: ItemService) => {
    spyOn(itemService, "update");
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SandboxComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges(); // It is best practices to call this after creating the component b/c we want to have a baseline rendered component (with ng2 change detection triggered) after we create the component and trigger all of its lifecycle events of which may cause the need for change detection to occur, in the case attempted template data bounding occurs.

    let componentUnderTest = fixture.componentInstance;

    componentUnderTest.saveItem("someValueIWantToSaveHEHEHE");

    tick(300); // avoliva :)

    expect(itemService.update).toHaveBeenCalled();

  })));

});
```

---

```
// component.sandbox.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { ItemService } from "../../Providers";

@Component({
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="formGroupInstance">
      <input formControlName="testFormControl" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      <button type="button" (click)="saveItem(formGroupInstance.controls['testFormControl'].value)">saveItem(...)</button>
    </form>
  `,
  styleUrls: ["component.sandbox.scss"],
})
export class SandboxComponent extends OnInit {
  public formGroupInstance: FormGroup;
  public testFormControlInstance: FormControl;

  constructor(private itemService: ItemService) {
    super();

    this.testFormControlInstance = new FormControl();

    this.formGroupInstance = new FormGroup(
      {
        testFormControl: this.testFormControlInstance,
      },
    );
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.testFormControlInstance.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(300) // avoliva
      .subscribe((formControlInstanceValue: {}) => {
        this.itemService.update(formControlInstanceValue);
      });
  }

  public saveItem(item: any) {
    this.testFormControlInstance.setValue(item);
  }

}
```

---

```
// ../../Provider/index.ts
export class ItemService {
  public update(formControlInstanceValue: any) {
    // Makes http request to api to update item
    console.log(`HEY PROGRAMMER, YEAH YOU! :P \n => http request could have been made
    here to update an 'item' in the database.`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using **setTimeout**. For example:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  expect(effects.yourRequest$).toBeObservable(yourResult$);
});
```